# 502 Error when executing python script from java servlet

Tags: python, java, iis

When trying to execute a python script from java side servlet, I am facing 502 error in some cases.
The script stops in the middle of execution and 502 error is returned
Our application is running in tomcat and IIS. Is there any config in IIS that can fix this issue

Below is the code used to run the python script.

```
String[] commandToRunPythonScript = { "py","-3",pyhtonScriptFilePathString,orgName};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToRunPythonScript);
process.waitFor();
BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

Note: The script works fine when it is executed from command prompt. Also it works fine in few cases when running from java side

Comment: Please, provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Yes, let me provide more details

Comment: This is the typical (bad) pattern that makes your web app slow to respond, and 502 errors are the expected result. However, the solution differs and must be found after thorough review of your web app (Java and Python) by a professional. You should hire an experienced consultant.

Comment: If your Python script takes too long to execute and the connection between Tomcat/IIS and the Python process times out, you may get a 502 error. You can try increasing the timeout settings in Tomcat or IIS and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: You may want to check the IIS logs for any error messages or other useful information that may help understand what is causing the 502 error.